# Following programming elixir book, having trouble with guard on list of lists

Tags: elixir

In the book, the author is using some `test_data`:

```
def test_data do
    [
     [1366225622, 26, 15, 0.125],
     [1366225622, 27, 15, 0.45],
     [1366225622, 28, 21, 0.25],
     [1366229222, 26, 19, 0.081],
     [1366229222, 27, 17, 0.468],
     [1366229222, 28, 15, 0.60],
     [1366232822, 26, 22, 0.095],
     [1366232822, 27, 21, 0.05],
     [1366232822, 28, 24, 0.03],
     [1366236422, 26, 17, 0.025]
    ]
  end
```

I am having trouble doing pattern matching to ensure the test_data is always following the right pattern of having a list of 4 things.  How can I make this work?  I think that part is outside of the scope of the exercise and lesson material, but I am struggling to figure it out.

```
  def for_loc([], _), do: IO.puts "Please provide valid data and location number!"
  def for_loc([head = [time, loc_id, temp, rain] | tail], loc), do: IO.puts "Valid"
```

Comment: This code is perfectly valid. What exactly you want to achieve with that?

Comment: If I pass it `[[1,2,3,4], [5, 6]], 5` it will be valid, but how to make sure the list itself is valid?  That is, it has 4 things in each inner list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iex(1)> defmodule B do
...(1)>   def for_loc([], _), do: IO.puts "Valid!"
...(1)>   def for_loc([[time, loc_id, temp, rain] | tail], loc), do: for_loc(tail, loc)
...(1)>   def for_loc(_, _), do: IO.puts "Invalid!"
...(1)> end
```

The problem is: when you use recursion, the last match would be against `for_loc([], _)` (the list on the last iteration is empty.)

What is invalid, should be handled with *separate match clause*, that would be hit *if no one before was hit*.

That said, when the array element does not match `[time, loc_id, temp, rain]`, the second clause won’t match *and the third one will*.

*Sidenote:* I have no idea what `loc` (second param) is, but your `test_data` does not provide it at all, hence I decided to just silently leave it intact.

---

*Mode details:* when one passes `test_data` to `for_loc`, there will be 10 hits of *second* match clause, then 1 hit of *first* match clause. Whjen one passes smth like you have specified in the comment, there will be 1 hit for *second* clause, and hit *of the third clause*, since neither first, nor second match.

The **recursion** is used here until the list is either empty, or invalid.